# New iOS release, what time are they traditionally released (on release day)?

Tags: ios

I was curious about what time apple traditionally has released its major iOS updates in the past?

I could see several times that make sense:

- at 12:00am PST?
- at midnight local time across the globe?

I wonder if past major releases are random/indeterminate when they come out?

(Of course, it takes some time to propagate the update through their CDN, and there really is no way to determine when any individual might get a change to download an iOS update)

Comment: There's this thing called twitter that will let you know when Apple releases new software :-) http://twitter.com/#!/search/iOS will hit thousands of posts a minute as soon as it's available.

Comment: @bmike good point, but I was curious so I could plan now to update in the morning or the evening. It would be easier for me to move stuff now rather than later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Apple software updates seem to get posted around 1PM Eastern/10AM Pacific. Far from a guarantee however, that's just my approximation based on past experience and a super quick Google to confirm.

Comment: I'd say it makes sense if you assume the release focuses when the majority of Apple's engineers would start their work day, but who knows what they've got planned this time. I wouldn't bet much on it, though ;-)

Comment: @bmike is the voice of reason. It's available when it's available. Depends on a lot factors. Impossible to answer definitively. Stop trying to parse the time and just go about your life. Some time tomorrow is the only plausible answer.

Answer (score -2):

At midnight or 1am local time.

Comment: Are you able to provide a citation or reference to support this statement? Even stating that it's a personal anecdote would improve this answer (if that's the case.)